# Why container styles are not applying to View component in React native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React project, In that project why container styles are not applying to View
Component in react native.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={([styles.container], {flex: 1}, {flexDirection: 'column'})}>
      <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
      <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
      <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should edit your view container style to this

```
style={[styles.container, {flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}]}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Yasuooooooooo how to split screen into six parts in horizontal way

Comment: You just need to set `flexDirection: 'row'` and add `flex: 1` with each of your child component style.